# How to prove $x^4+y^4\leq (x^2+y^2)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> I want to prove: $$x^4+y^4\leq (x^2+y^2)^2 \tag 1$$

We always have $x^2\geq 0$ and $y^2\geq 0$. Therefore we also have $x^4\geq 0$ and $y^4\geq 0$.

Addition of the inequalities gives
$$
x^4+y^4\geq 0 \tag 2
$$
I now add $2x^2y^2$ to both sides, so
\begin{align}
x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2&\geq 2x^2y^2 \tag 3 \\
(x^2+y^2)^2&\geq 2x^2y^2 \tag 4
\end{align}
I'm stuck here...

Comment: Expand the RHS of $\mathrm {(1)}$, then it could be reduced to $2x^2y^2\geqslant0$, which is true for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

$$(x^2+y^2)^2=x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4\geqslant x^4+y^4.$$

Comment: Hi! I grasp this by intuition but not algebraically, can we just "remove" the term $2x^2y^2$ and add the inequality-sign?

Comment: @Donsert Yes, because $2x^2y^2\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$2x^2y^2\geq 0$$ for all real $x,y$
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2$$